# Making all cells the same width (with jQuery?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

If I have the following table structure:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width=100%>
<tr>
    <th>
    </th>
    <th>
    Col Header 1
    </th>
    <th>
    Col Header 2
    </th>
    <th>
    Col Header 3
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>
    Row Header
    </th>
    <td>
    cell 1
    </td>
    <td>
    cell 2
    </td>
    <td>
    cell 3
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

How do I make all TDs the same width? Please note I have TH at the beginning of my rows. I'm OK to use jQuery if needed.

---

EDIT:

From suggestions below I am starting to lean more towards jQuery solution. Basically what I'll need to do it:

1. Get a width of TABLE
2. Get a width of TH at the beginning of ROW
3. Subtract #2 from #1
4. Divide the rest by number of TDs

I think it's a bit convoluted but should do the job...

Comment: Ah, one thing just hit me. Are you asking how to let the columns vary in width depending on content, but set all columns to be the same width as the widest one? Because that would be a completely different problem than the one we have all answered thus far... and, it would be quite a bit harder...

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason you can't use CSS?

```
td {
    width: 300px;
}
```

If you want all TD:s *and* TH:s to be the same width, just set the width on the TH instead:

```
th {
    width: 300px;
}
```

The TD:s will get their width from the column, and the column will get it's width from the TH:s.

EDIT: The edit to your question makes it much easier to understand what you want to do :)

I would definitely look into doing this with CSS Flexible Box Model (flexbox) for compatible browsers. http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

You can use Modernizr to check for flexbox compatibility: http://www.modernizr.com/

Due to the possible messiness of the code needed to do what you want with javascript, I would also consider whether less enabled browsers *really* need this feature or not.

Not that it would be impossible to implement it in javascript though, not at all.

If the data in the table is static once loaded, it should be pretty straight forward to grab the width of the table and first column, and split the remainder over the rest of the columns.

If the content of the table might change after being initially loaded however, you will need to sort out how to check for changes and re-apply the new style every time. You will probably place some event listeners, but which events you need to listen for depends on what actions might change the content of the table...

Also, remember that a user might zoom the text of the web page. This might mess up the width of the columns too, I guess...

Comment: Just a thought, because he is using ths on the side (not top), wouldn't that only align the first column

Comment: He is using TH:s on top. See the content of the first TR. Otherwise, you would be correct, yes.

Comment: I don't know what the with of the table may be.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice the first tr was only ths.

Comment: I use TH both on the top -- for column headers and at the beginning of each TR for ROW headers.

Comment: @santa, if you know how many 'columns' there'll be, use a percentage instead of a `px` width.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do it with css.
You should add th if you need them though.
Something like

```
table tr td
{
    width: 400px;
}
```

Or, with jquery

```
$('table tr td').each(function() {$(this).css('width','400px');});
```

Or revised (by Adrian)

```
$('table tr td').css('width','400px');
```

Comment: You don't need to call .each() -- $('table tr td').css('width','400px'); will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to style `td` widths when you know the pixel width of the table.

For instance, if the `width = 300px` then each `td` could be styled at 100px.

However, if your table must be `width = 100%` then you could set the width on each `td` to 33%.

If you have `padding`, `margins`, or `borders` on the `table`, those will affect the width of the `td`.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width in percentage:

```
td, th { width: 33%; }
```